# Jack and Jack stand points for a 2011 Hyundai Elantra besides the tire jack points?

Tags: hyundai, elantra, jack, jack-stand

My floor jack and jack stands do not fit slot for the emergency the scissor jack. I know I can jack the car up from the front tow hooks. Can I jack it safely from the center of the beam those two tow hooks are on? Where exactly should I place standard jack stands.

If I have to jack up the rear of the car what jack points are available to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place your jack under the rear cross member, like #17 in the picture below, to lift it. The cross-member is what all the suspension parts are attached to. It is one of the strongest parts of the car as the entire car is supported by it.

[image]

Once you jack the car, it is safest to put the jack stands where the scissor jack points are. That is the widest location and will be very stable.

If you are concerned about damaging the body at the jack points, there are these jack pads that will protect it.

[image]

You can find them on Amazon.com by searching "Universal Slotted Frame Rubber Jack Pad". There are various sizes, so choose wisely for your car.

Comment: I know those round style supports work with floor jacks, but how would they would with jack stands? I'm thinking of just getting new jack stands that have really deep grooves.

Comment: That will work too. The important thing is to place them correctly to be safely stable.

Comment: Those jack pads are cool, but out of the 10 different ones I look at none of them list a load capacity.

Comment: You are right. I couldn't find a capacity either. Likely made of Nitrile rubber, the capacity is probably quite high.

Answer (score 2):

1. Look for long beams that run (most of) the length of the car. You will often find brake lines and fuel lines attached to these. These beams are my favourite places to place stands, just stay away form the brake linres and fuel lines.
2. Look for flat spots that look like they have more than 1 piece of metal overlapping.
3. NEVER use the actual floor of the car. It's very thin.